# Removing views, ARC, differences from Objective C and Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, automatic-ref-counting

In Objective C, if a ViewController has a UIKit object property, lets just say a view, and is instantiated in viewDidLoad, followed by being added to the subview, in order to remove it out of memory, both removeFromSuperview() and setting the object to nil must be done (if I'm not mistaken, but I could be...)

However, in Swift, only things with the optional type can hold a value of nil.

My question is, if I would like to animate things like UILabels or UIViews within my application, and later have them disappear (to both the user and removed from memory), would having that UIKit object being removeFromSuperView() be enough? or would I have to make all objects that I'm trying to animate optional, removeFromSuperView() and then set them to nil?

I apologize for my poor articulation.  If further clarification is needed, please let me know.  Much thanks for your input.

Comment: Subviews are typically optional in swift, because they are initialized _after_ the parent object (and non-optional properties need to have a value before initialization of the owning instance finishes). That's why you see e.g.  `@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!` all the time (`?` would do, too, but is less convenient)

Comment: @NicolasMiari is correct. I'd like to add 2 things: 1) that there is very little reason to NOT make a UIView-type property an optional. It simplifies initialization of your UIViewControllers, and 2) removeFromSuperView simply calls UIView.removeSubview(:UIView); it does not set an object to nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `weak` property objects to deallocate, then yes, you have to set them to `nil` or wait for the owning object to deallocate.

Objects in properties that are not `weak` will get a `release` call when the parent object is deallocated. This means the objects will also get deallocated if nothing else is keeping a reference to them.

If you create a temporary `UILabel` that's not a property of the View Controller and animate it and then `removeFromSuperview()` it, then it should disappear from memory as well.

As it was retained `(refcount: 1)` when the function creating the animation was running, later by the view hierarchy `(refcount: 2)`, the function ended `(refcount: 1)`, so only the view hierarchy was retaining it. If you removed it at the end of animation `(refcount: 0)` it is deallocated.